# Service Fabric - Stateful Service Memory Footprint

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When using stateful services (Reliable Services model), we observe that the baseline memory footprint per process is approximately 250MB of unmanaged memory and approximately 20MB of managed memory (in this scenario, it is simply a Stateful Web API with no other code, created from the Visual Studio templates).

In our application, we use this model, hosting our services in a single Service Fabric Application (with ServicePackageActivationMode.SharedProcess). Our application partitions data by tenants (conceptually a customer) and namespaces within a tenant (a container for a subset of the customer’s data). So, there may be 0 to many tenants, and each tenant may have 0 to many namespaces, all hosted in a single process (with secondary replicas on other nodes).

So, we have one process per node with a baseline memory of approximately 300MB of unmanaged memory and 20MB of managed memory. Of note, we are using .NET 5 (migrating to 6) so none of the unmanaged memory is directly ours, rather it is the Service Fabric overhead.

Our goal is to isolate tenants to minimize noisy neighbors, as well as allow better load balancing, roll out upgrades on a per-customer basis, among other potential benefits. So, we are considering changing our hosting model such that, rather than multi-tenancy as we have now, we want to have a Service Fabric Application per tenant (still using “Shared Process”), thus if we have ‘N’ tenants, each node will have ‘N’ processes, rather than the single process we currently use.

What concerns us is the baseline memory footprint (i.e., the ~250-300MB of unmanaged memory) per process. Even in the multi-tenancy model, each process has a similar baseline memory overhead. We expect to have many tenants hosted within a single cluster. So, if there are 100 tenants, with the application-per-tenant model, we would have an ambient memory overhead of more than 24GB without any customer data being in-process. Testing with “Exclusive Process”, we see similar baseline memory footprints. Even stateless services exhibit a similar baseline memory footprint.

Since we leverage Reliable Collections (RCs), we have not attempted to use a Guest Executable model, nor have we tried Reliable Actors (probably not a good fit anyway since we have I/O going to BLOB storage, along with querying across a subset of instances). Although we are researching alternatives to RCs to potentially decouple from Service Fabric.

My overall question then: Is the baseline memory footprint on a per-process basis just the cost of doing business with Service Fabric? I am curious if others have seen this same memory footprint, as well as if there are any ways to optimize (reduce) the memory.

Comment: You might consider raising exactly this question at the next SF community call: https://aka.ms/sfcommunityqa

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.